Why does the measurable uniformization property imply all sets are measurable?
In The strength of measurability hypotheses, Raisonnier and Stern formulated the following principle:

(MUP). For any family $(A_x)_{x\in B}$ of non-empty subsets of
$2^\omega$, indexed by the elements of a set $B$ of positive measure,
there is a Borel function $f$, such that $\{x\in B\mid f(x)\notin A_x\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

They proceed to note that MUP implies the measurability of all sets. The argument: "in order to prove the measurability of $A$, one just uniformizes its characteristic function."
My question is: what does this mean? The characteristic function $\chi_A$ of $A$ is a subset of $(2^\omega)^2$, but I don't see how uniformizing it can get us anywhere (or needs the MUP to begin with). So it would seem I am missing something obvious.

Pick any two different  points $a$ and $b$ from $2^\omega$. Let $A_x=\{a\}$ if $x\in B$ and $A_x=\{b\}$ otherwise. If $f$ is a uniformization, then $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is a Borel set that equals $B$ up to a set of measure zero. Since Lebesgue measure is complete, $B$ must be measurable. Since $B$ was arbitrary, every set must be measurable.

I'm confused; I thought the index set (B in this case) is assumed to be measurable to begin with, when we assumed it to be of positive measure. Or did I misunderstand the assumption (or your argument)?

@ikrto I think all the $B$s in Michael Greinecker's answer should be $A$s.

Thanks, @AlexKruckman . I am still not seeing this. So we set out to establish measurability of a set, and we use it as the index set in the proof. But doesn't MUP assume the index set is of positive measure, and hence measurable to begin with?

@ikrto The index set is $B = 2^\omega$.

@ikrto It should be fixed now.

Oh I see it now. Let $A$ be arbitrary and for $x\in 2^\omega$, set $A_x = {1}$ if $x\in A$ and $A_x={0}$ otherwise. Then the uniformization map is the characteristic function of $A$ up to a measure zero set. Thanks Michael and Alex! It never occurred to me that the $A_x$'s are singletons!
